# Dump entire webform database into excel file or csv?

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, database

I want to download all of the data from this database for the following criteria:
Year: 2010-11 ; State: ODISHA ; District: [ALL] ; Tehsil: [ALL] ; Tables: [Cropping Pattern] ; Social Group: [ALL] ; Crop: [potato, onion, tomato, brinjal, spinach]

Unfortunately, I only have the webform link: http://agcensus.dacnet.nic.in/TalukCharacteristics.aspx

I could just do it by hand (the webform will let you eventually download a given query to an excel file) but I would have to do 1000s of queries by hand :(

I do eventually want all the data in excel but that's just a ton of clicks. Any advice on how to automate this would be super useful (I have some programming experience with python and Matlab). Thanks in advance!

PS I'm super new to this kind of thing, so sorry in advance. A friend of mine needs this for their dissertation

Comment: how many table ?

Comment: You should change the title to dump rather than download, as the two have two different meanings.

Comment: could you show me your data model ? (all the tables that store the data you want in your csv; I suppose you want a single big table ?)

Comment: Yeah a big single table would be the best case scenario, its easier for me to run analyses on.

Comment: My criteria for the database is: Year: 2010-11 ; State: ODISHA ; District: [ALL] ; Tehsil: [ALL] ; Tables: [Cropping Pattern] ; Social Group: [ALL] ; Crop: [potato, onion, tomato, brinjal, spinach]

Comment: Do you have access to the actual database directly? That’s be the easiest.

Comment: @Paul

Unfortunately the only access I have is this link: http://agcensus.dacnet.nic.in/TalukCharacteristics.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source files of the site in question, you'll see that they fetch the data in the file talukCharacteristic.js, using jquery like so:

```
function GetddlData(ddl_valueField, ddl_TextField, CallFor) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'TalukCharacteristics.aspx/Get_ddlData',
        data: "{'value':'" + ddl_valueField + "','Text':'" + ddl_TextField + "','CallFor':'" + CallFor + "'}",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {

            var vData = JSON.parse(data);

            if (vData.d.Flag == 'n') {
                alert('Invalid year.');
                return false;
            }
            else {
                BindState(vData.d.State);
                BindDistrict(vData.d.District);
                BindTable(vData.d.Tables);
                BindSocialGroup(vData.d.socialgroup);
                BindCrop(vData.d.Crops);
            }
        },
        error: function (vData) {
            alert('Error Occured during binding.');
        }
    });
}
```

This implies that there's a URL ('/TalukCharacteristics.aspx/Get_ddlData/) you can POST a query to with the parameters you want.  You could do this with `curl` from the command line or Postman, and it'll (as configured) return a JSON object which you could then convert into CSV or other formats at your leisure.